# Error in Oviyam and Oviyam2 not working with TLS encryption

Tags: dicom, tls1.2, dcm4che

I have configure my DCM4CHEE using TLS encryption https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ee2/Setting+up+DCM4CHEE+with+TLS++encryption
but not working properly

https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ee2/TLS+Configuration

My dcm4chee-web3 working fine , and also getting echo successfully of DCM4CHEE and port number 11112 
[image: DCM4CHEE ECHO SUCCESSFULLY]

when i start oviyam its give error 
[image]
[image]

I have configure my dicom-dcm4chee-local.properties and weasis-pacs-connector.properties this here 
http://davidsimic.com/2016/06/13/dcm4chee-getting-weasis-working-w-tls/

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the solution
form this link 
I follow this link to configure

> weasis-pacs-connector.properties

and

> dicom-dcm4chee-local.properties,

also attached this property

http://davidsimic.com/2016/06/13/dcm4chee-getting-weasis-working-w-tls/

I have created certificate from this link for client and server

http://davidsimic.com/2016/06/06/dcm4chee-security-setting-up-tls-encryption/

I have also changed this files in resource CDimseService.cfg,SaveFilesystem.cfg,EchoService.cfg,StorageService.cfg,Study.cfg files
I have changed little bit code in AE.java file for tls protocol

you can download source code of oviyam from here
https://sourceforge.net/p/dcm4che/svn/14705/tree/oviyam/oviyam/tags/0_9_1/

follow this link for all attachment and solution

[DCM4CHEE google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dcm4che/5wWliDVEbLw)

i give solution here with attached file

Thanks